# Is schema registry required with any kafka avro set up?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream

Very new to Kafka and getting very confused with multiple tutorials. 
Is schema registry required with any kafka avro set up?
How to setup with a spring boot-Kafka project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring docs, you can find simple example to see and understand basic requirements to setup spring-kafka project. From maven repository to basic producer and consumer configs. Here is the link: [A Very, Very Quick Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#a-very-very-quick-example)

In addition to above example, to setup your kafka APIs for Schema Registry, you need to have below configurations

**For producer:**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
```

**For consumer:**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupName);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, false);
props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
```

Above configs work for me when I use `kafka_2.11-2.1.1` along with `SR-5.1.2`. Hope this helps

Comment: Is it mandatory to have  a schema registry for Kafka?

Comment: No it is not, you can use kafka plain. Schema registry allows you to send your complex data in a tidy, human readable format. To use kafka plain, follow the configs in the link, you do not need additional configs that I mentioned above

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask one last thing what is the tidy format it sends in

Comment: Welcome, you can see a schema sample here in this link. [sample](https://mapr.com/docs/61/Kafka/KafkaSchemaRegistry/KafkaSchemaRegistryDemo.html) , if you send employee class data without SR, it would be messy I think

Answer (score 4):

> Is schema registry required with any kafka avro set up?

Kafka messages are *just bytes*. It's up to you how you serialise them. If you use Avro (or Protobuf, or JSON Schema) then you can use the Confluent Schema Registry which includes serialisers & deserialisers for these, and stores the schema for you whilst embedding in the actual message stored on Kafka a pointer to it.

In theory you could write raw Avro to Kafka and manage the `.avsc` schema file yourself - this is in *theory*. In *practice* people just use the Schema Registry.

Ref:

- [Yes, Virginia, You Really Do Need a Schema Registry](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-kafka-stream-processing-yes-virginia-you-really-need-one?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-16&utm_term=rmoff-devx)
- [Confluent Platform Now Supports Protobuf, JSON Schema, and Custom Formats](https://www.confluent.io/blog/confluent-platform-now-supports-protobuf-json-schema-custom-formats/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-16&utm_term=rmoff-devx)
- [Schemas, Contracts, and Compatibility](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schemas-contracts-compatibility?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-16&utm_term=rmoff-devx)

> How to setup with a spring boot-Kafka project.

Try [this tutorial](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-16&utm_term=rmoff-devx)

Comment: Great. Don't forget StackOverflow etiquette to mark answers as helpful or correct if they are :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, [Confluent Schema Registry](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/index.html) is not required to produce/consume [Apache AVRO](https://avro.apache.org) records in the key or value of a Kafka record.

Apache AVRO is a self-contained data container format, where a payload is always accompanied by its schema. In doing so, it is always possible for a reader to interpret the payload together with the schema.

Schema Registry is a supplementary service by Confluent which serves as a central registry for *all* AVRO schemas used within a given Kafka cluster environment.

Confluent provides [Avro Schema Serializer and Deserializer](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html). Serializer registers each schema with the registry and replaces the schema part of the AVRO record with a unique id returned by the registry. Deserializer on the other hand can query the schema from the registry using the same schema id. This saves storage in the cluster, because schemas are not repeated with each record. On the other hand, it increases network traffic and coupling.

On top, it can benefit consistent evolution of producer/consumer contracts, see [Schema Evolution and Compatibility](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html).

For integration of Schema Registry with Spring, I refer you to the documentation of [Spring Kafka](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) and [Spring Cloud Schema Registry](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-schema-registry).